# How to improve performance on mobile devices using xamarin forms

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism, portable-class-library

We are using xamarin forms with prism. We have simple pages with small amount of data to be displayed on each page and include simple calculations.  We are using prism navigation service to navigate between pages. We are experiencing some latency from clicking a button to navigating to next page. Data is fetched inside OnNavigatedTo since navigation parameter changes the data. Can someone shed some light of why is there a latency, it is close 1+ second and sometimes 2 seconds.

Also, it seems like each page is getting rendered twice... Once before OnNaviagatedTo and then data changes.  OnProperty or OnCollection changed is fired from within OnNavigatedTo and it seems to cause the rendering again.

Answer (score 2):

Version 6.3.0 introduced the concept of `OnNavigatingTo`, while `OnNavigatedTo` has been around for a while. There is a distinct difference between the two. Understanding the order in which things occur should help you create a nicer user experience.

- New Page is created
- OnNavigatedFrom is called
- OnNavigatingTo is called
- New Page is pushed onto the Navigation Stack and becomes visible
- OnNavigatedTo is called

Applications that have to reach out and fetch data can often experience latency issues because it takes time to reach out to the remote service and get the data we want and then parse that data into a usable object. This particular problem was one in which many developers wanted to cut down the demand on the UI with having to refresh as the bindings were being updated which led to the introduction of `OnNavigatingTo`.

While neither one will reduce network latency it gives you an ability to make the calling page enter an `IsBusy` state that may display some sort of loading icon which would then be updated to false when `NavigateAsync` completes and your new page is displayed already loaded.